# SQL string replacement workaround

Tags: sql, string, sybase

I'm working in a modified version of Sybase 10 that doesn't have the stuff, replace or str_replace functions.  I need to replace part of string in a number of records.

Are there any creative ways to program around this, so I don't have to do them all manually?

Example:

```
UPDATE status
SET description = replace(description,'abc','def')
WHERE name = 'test'
```

**EDIT:**  I've found that we have NO string-manipulation functions and I'll have to do exports and imports to do bulk string changes.  I'll leave this question up so others who aren't quite restricted as I am will be able to find the answers.

Comment: What functions can you use? All string functions are disabled?

Comment: I think have have the basic ones, like right, left, mid etc, but I haven't tested them all.  This is a vendor-modified sybase installation and I don't have a complete list of what does and doesn't work.  Plus it's complicated by the age of the installation (1999-2000).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
UPDATE status
SET description = SUBSTRING(description,1,CHARINDEX('abc',description)-1) 
                  + 'def' + 
                  SUBSTRING(description,CHARINDEX('abc',description)+CHAR_LENGTH('abc'),CHAR_LENGTH(description)-CHARINDEX('abc',description))
WHERE name = 'test'
```

Tricky and you have to put the text you want to change in few places, but it works ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A combination of charindex and substring should work for you.